# Python - Division by zero

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can i make something divided by 0 equal base, EX:

`5/0` output ***5***

Sorry I can't explain properly, I'm new to programming

Comment: You can use `try except` to catch `ZeroDivisionError`.

Comment: thinkabout what you need : check whether the denominator is zero or note to return the division or the numerator only : that seems to be an `if/else` condition, do you know about that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to do this, the normal way I do it is like this. Note this will also output 5 if `n` is negative. I typically use this when averaging collections that might be empty, since negative lengths are impossible.

```
result = 5/max(1, n)
```

Will output 5 if n is 0 or negative. Very compact and useful in big equations.

Other way with `if`:

```
if n!=0:
    result = 5/n
else:
    result = 5
```

Or with `try`:

```
try:
    result = 5/n
except ZeroDivisionError:
    result = 5
```

Comment: In what sense is your first suggestion "the normal way"? A negative denominator won't cause any issues. Using the *max()* idea will make the division result incorrect (sign swap)

Comment: The normal way is the way I do it 90% of the time. When I use functions like this `n` is typically the length of a collection so can't possibly be negative.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `or`:

```
n = 0
5/(n or 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the requirement is mathematically incorrect, this is best dealt with by wrapping the implementation in a function.

```
def divide(x, y):
  return x if y == 0 else x / y
```

Comment: I use functions like this all the time, mostly for things like taking the average of a list that might be empty. It being incorrect doesn't mean it's not useful.