# How can I plot a mathematical function, if there is the case with division by zero?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

My task is to plot a mathematical function in Python for my college homework. How can I define this function, if there is a sin in the denominator? First I had to write the function down and compute it. The case of division by zero I did with the L'Hospital.

I'm uploading the photos of my results for both cases. My job is to plot the case theta unequal to zero divided by the case theta equal zero for some frequencies.

My questions are:

1. What do I wrong while defining these functions?
2. How can I plot it?

   ```
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

   def find_nearest(array, value):
       array = np.asarray(array)
       index = np.abs(array - value).argmin()
       return index

   def dB(x):
       return 20*np.log10(np.abs(x))
       f = np.array([125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000])
   theta = np.array([0, 30, 60, 90])

   f = np.arange(start=125, stop=16001, step=1)
   theta = np.deg2rad(np.arange(start=0, stop=360, step=1))

   F, THETA = np.meshgrid(f, theta, indexing='ij')

   i = 0 + 1j
   c = 340
   k  = (2 * np.pi * F) / c


   f_neq0 = (-5) / (k * sin_the) * np.sin(2.5 * k * sin_the)
   f_0 = (-2.5 * i) / (np.pi * F)
   Gamma = f_neq0 / f_0

   figure(figsize=(10,10))
   ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1, polar=True)
   ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')

   for t in [125, 250, 500, 1000]:
       index = find_nearest(f,t)
       plt.plot(theta[:180], dB(Gamma[index,0:180]))
   for p in [2000, 4000, 8000, 16000]:
       index = find_nearest(f,p)
       plt.plot(theta[181:361], dB(Gamma[index,181:361]))
   ```

These are the warnings I get:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  f_neq0 = (-5) / (k * sin_the) * np.sin(2.5 * k * sin_the)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  f_neq0 = (-5) / (k * sin_the) * np.sin(2.5 * k * sin_the)
```

The functions don't start at 0°. What can I change?

[my results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqv3N.jpg) 
[my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyK8e.jpg)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a way of solving those cases of division by zero, don't you?

Comment: The task is to devide the theta not zero case by theta zero case. I don't know how to pick the theta = 0 for the denominator of division from the array of theta's and to to plot this division for 8 different frequences.

Comment: Then your problem is not about how to plot, but how to apply a different calculation when the denominator is zero. The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72150209/15032126

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Division by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72150139/python-division-by-zero)

Comment: No, it doesn't...

Comment: To find the position in the array where sin(x)==0 use `idx = np.nonzero(np.sin(x)==0)` then replace that value in f.

Comment: I can't run your code. What's `sin_the`? Can you please make the code runnable? Thanks!